# NetBeansでラズベリパイ(Raspberry)のPi4Jを使用して、付属のサンプルコードを実行したところこのようなエラーが発生して、実行ができません。何が原因かわかるでしょうか？

Tags: raspberry-pi

```
7 24, 2015 10:07:52 午前 com.pi4j.util.NativeLibraryLoader load
重大: Unable to load [libpi4j.so] using path: [/lib/libpi4j.so]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The path has to be absolute, but found: \lib\libpi4j.so
    at com.pi4j.util.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryFromClasspath(NativeLibraryLoader.java:120)
    at com.pi4j.util.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:92)
    at com.pi4j.wiringpi.Gpio.<clinit>(Gpio.java:174)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiGpioProvider.<init>(RaspiGpioProvider.java:51)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory.getDefaultProvider(GpioFactory.java:106)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.impl.GpioControllerImpl.<init>(GpioControllerImpl.java:54)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory.getInstance(GpioFactory.java:89)
    at ControlGpioExample.main(ControlGpioExample.java:51)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.pi4j.wiringpi.Gpio.wiringPiSetup()I
    at com.pi4j.wiringpi.Gpio.wiringPiSetup(Native Method)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiGpioProvider.<init>(RaspiGpioProvider.java:51)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory.getDefaultProvider(GpioFactory.java:106)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.impl.GpioControllerImpl.<init>(GpioControllerImpl.java:54)
    at com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory.getInstance(GpioFactory.java:89)
    at ControlGpioExample.main(ControlGpioExample.java:51)
Java Result: 1
```